# How to wrap html when running foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

i have a loop like this below

```
foreach( $b as $entry) {

    $title2 = "<!doctype html>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>";

  $title2 .= "<div class='data'><div id=".$id."><span style='font-family: Web'>".$entry->pubDate."&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href='../../fetch.php?url=".$id."' title='$entry->title' >" .$title. "</a><br/><div class='content'>".$description."</div></div></div>";


  $title3 = "<!doctype html>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../../css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body><div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-lg-12' style='margin-top:20px;'>";


$title3 .= "<div class='list-group'><a href='../../../fetch.php?url=".$id."' title='$entry->title' class='list-group-item' > <i class='fa fa-chevron-right rt'></i><div class='title'><div id=".$id."><span style='font-family: Malithi Web'>".$entry->pubDate."&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'<div><h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>'" .$title. "</h4></div><br/></div></div></div></div></div></div></a></div>";


if (!file_exists('File')) {
    mkdir('File', 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists('./File/'.date("Y-m-d"))) {
    mkdir('./File/'.date("Y-m-d"), 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists('./File/titles/'.date("Y-m-d"))) {
    mkdir('./File/titles/'.date("Y-m-d"), 0777, true);
}

$File = './File/'.date("Y-m-d").'/'."File.html"; 
file_put_contents($File, $title2, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$FileT = './File2/titles/'.date("Y-m-d").'/'."File2.html"; 
file_put_contents($FileT, $title3, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);




}//foreach end
```

**When i save the file what i want is to save it with html head and styles..but now it is saving for each time when the loop runs..i want it for just run once.**

Thank you!

Comment: You could use a [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) or limit the number of elements in `$b` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to have two dayly log files with the same data but differently formatted?
Then move your header , footer and filenaming logic outside of your loop.

```
<?php
foreach ($b as $entry) {
    $body2 .= "<div class='data'><div id=" . $id . "><span style='font-family: Web'>" . $entry->pubDate . "&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href='../../fetch.php?url=" . $id . "' title='$entry->title' >" . $title . "</a><br/><div class='content'>" . $description . "</div></div></div>";
    $body3 .= "<div class='list-group'><a href='../../../fetch.php?url=" . $id . "' title='$entry->title' class='list-group-item' > <i class='fa fa-chevron-right rt'></i><div class='title'><div id=" . $id . "><span style='font-family: Malithi Web'>" . $entry->pubDate . "&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'<div><h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>'" . $title . "</h4></div><br/></div></div></div></div></div></div></a></div>";
}

if (!file_exists('File')) {
    mkdir('File', 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists('./File/' . date("Y-m-d"))) {
    mkdir('./File/' . date("Y-m-d"), 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists('./File/titles/' . date("Y-m-d"))) {
    mkdir('./File/titles/' . date("Y-m-d"), 0777, true);
}

$File = './File/' . date("Y-m-d") . '/' . "File.html";

$title2 = "<!doctype html>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>";

$footer2 = "</body></html>";
file_put_contents($File, $title2 . $body2 . $footer2, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

$title3 = "<!doctype html>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../../css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body><div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-12' style='margin-top:20px;'>";


$footer3 = "</div></div></div></body></html>";

$FileT = './File2/titles/' . date("Y-m-d") . '/' . "File2.html";
file_put_contents($FileT, $title3 . $body3 . $footer3, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```